# Dynamic function creation in Metaclass

Tags: python

I'm doing my first steps in Python 2.7 Metaprogramming, and wrote following code :

```
class MetaClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "Defining class : %s" % (cls,)
        ra = [(key, value) for key, value in cls.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('_')]
        for (k, v) in ra:
            setattr(cls, "_"+k, v)
            def get_a(cls):
                print "Getting value of " + k
            get_a(cls)
            get_a.__name__ = "get_" + k
            get_a.__doc__ = "Documentation for get_" + k
            setattr(cls,get_a.__name__, get_a)
            print get_a.__name__, get_a.__doc__

class BaseObject(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
    pass
```

And then :

```
class Pers(BaseObject):
    nom = "Toune"
    prenom = "Fabien"

p = Pers()
```

I was expecting to have two distinct functions "p.get_nom()" and "p.get_prenom()"
Btw, those two functions return the same result ("Getting value of prenom"), whereas they have distinct **name** and **doc**

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
def get_a(cls):
    print "Getting value of " + k
```

to

```
def get_a(cls, k=k):
    print "Getting value of " + k
```

to make this work.  There is only one local variable `k`, and the local function `get_a()` will always access the current value of this variable.  After finishing the loop, `k` will keep its last value.

Answer (score 5):

Ah yes, [closures](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/). Read that article then come back.

```
    for (k, v) in ra:
        setattr(cls, "_"+k, v)
        def new_method(val):
            def inner_get_a(cls):
                print "Getting value of " + val
            return inner_get_a
        get_a = new_method(k)
        get_a(cls)
        get_a.__name__ = "get_" + k
        get_a.__doc__ = "Documentation for get_" + k
        setattr(cls,get_a.__name__, get_a)
        print get_a.__name__, get_a.__doc__
```